# Web apps and using absolute layout

Tags: javascript, web-applications, layout, css-position

I'm working on a web app that I want to operate more like a standard OS app.  It is similar in layout to iTunes where I have a top header, a menubar beneath it, and then a left-sidebar and a main content area.  The goal is that everything stays where it's at on the screen and only the main section scrolls (because it has a grid/table of content).

I can accomplish this by using absolute positioning, adding overflows, specifying top/left/top/bottom, and automatic scrolling when applicable.  However, I'm not sure this is the best approach.  I did some research here on SO and the web and didn't find a conclusive answer.

I know it works, but is it a valid or acceptable approach?  My goal is to get it working but working using proper standards and acceptable approaches.

I could use a Javascript framework that accomplishes this as well (extjs, some jquery libraries, etc) but I think they do the same thing, they just do it dynamically at page load instead of specifying it up front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS has pretty lousy support for web application-style UI layout. There are promising specifications on the way, like css3-grids and css3-flexbox. But the browser support is lacking, especially the css3-grid.

When I implement a web app today, position: absolute, seems like the least worst option. It's flexible enough and meets most of the requirements.

There is a good blog post that talks more about this: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/10/05/full-height-app-layouts-a-css-trick-to-make-it-easier/

Comment: Accepted the answer a few years later, but completely missed this answer! This is a really good article, even several years after this question was answered.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, if it works it works, if it doesn't it doesn't. Standards, best practices, etc. are great and all, but only inasmuch as they help you to accomplish the actual goal. An app that's done the "wrong way" but is up-and-running is infinitely better than the "properly" built app that will be built eventually, once everybody's figured out what exactly the proper way is. That said, it sounds like your approach makes complete sense.